# How to automatically detect an input from a column and updates into a different range

Tags: google-sheets

[image: 1]

Hi, I would like some help with a current project or to know if it's possible to have a script for this.

For example, when someone makes changes a students lesson (column J) from Lesson 5 to Lesson 6 but didn't input a date,  the script would add a text "DATE PLS" to the respective student's row at the respective Lessons (L5 & L6)

It will be used for several other sheets too. About 24-26 other sheets.

Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

for inserting text `DATE PLS` you will need a script but if you are fine only with the red cell you can use conditional formatting like:

```
=(J4<>"")*(W4="")
```

on range W4:W

Comment: I'll try try this out, thank you!